# LM317 current limiting/set via differential amplifier works in simulator but glitchy when built

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-limiting, lm317

I am trying to build a single LM317 power supply, with current limiting using a differential opamp and potentiometers.

I've came up with this (see schematic) and have built it on a breadboard but the current limiting (1k pot, lower left) is "glitchy."

- Sometimes it will not limit at very low load resistor values (~1 ohm) but when the load resistor gets bigger it starts working.
- Sometimes when the load resistor comes back from a high value to a low value (while in current limiting,) the current limiting breaks down and it allows a large current to flow.
- A lot of the times I can't adjust the current below ~10mA no matter the set voltage.  I am not sure if it ever worked on the breadboard, but it works in the simulator.  I can set very low current in the simulator eg. 10uA. I know the LM317 needs a few mA flowing out of the pin for it to regulate but it dosen't even want to go below 10mA in a lot of load/voltage scenarios.
- Other glitches.

I used:

- LM224n
- LM317t
- BC547 (NPN)
- Capacitors 100nF ceramic  and 10uF electrolytic
- Resistors 5% or 1% (not final)
- 6x AA cells for the +9V supply
- 2x AA cells for 3.3V (reversed for negative rail)
- Diodes for the voltage reference (not final)

---

Schematic:

[image: psu schematic lm317 lm224]

What am I doing wrong?

Does this circuit makes sense?

Circuit:

[image: breadborad photo1]

Comment: Explain your voltage buffer on the right in more detail. It looks to me as though your 1 nF is essentially in parallel to your 100 nF (with a tiny ESR added?) Is that your read, as well, and your intention? I'm guessing you wanted a slew-rate limited adjustment of voltage. But I'd like to know your thinking in more detail. You have two controls interacting at the same site and I don't want to look at the left side until I've gathered the right, in detail. (Others may be faster at their uptake. So forgive me.)

Comment: The ESR is just for the simulator (no resistance capacitor loop error).
I have detected some high frequency ripple in the voltage control circuit, in the simulation and wanted to fix that. (~50kHz if i measured correctly)
And yes slower slew rate, at least for the simulation.

Comment: And you want your voltage sense/potentiometer set resistor divider chain tied back to the input voltage, after the current limit resistor that is also under control, and not the output voltage that the load sees?

Comment: That was the first setup, but i wanted forced voltage via adjust pin, may change that if i need to.

Comment: I don't see why you'd go there, at all, myself. I am frankly confused by that choice. So I'll let others have at this unless you write something that allows me to understand the thinking or I find a way to understand it on my own. (Which I doubt, as it just doesn't make sense to me.) Also, what's the minimum current that the LM317 you are using requires in order to remain in control??

Comment: This is not a final design, the  voltage control is not a problem, it works both this way and divider on the output way. My biggest problem is the current control glitches.
LM317 from STM 3,5mA typical.

Comment: Well, I think you are not working with a reasoned topology. That you imagine your biggest problem is with control glitches and that your topology for testing is itself reasonable ... is the biggest problem from my perception. There are a host of missing considerations present. So we see different things. That's partly why I'm walking back and letting my betters cover this.

Comment: I can't see how your voltage control section is supposed to work with a varying input voltage. There's no fixed reference for that part of the circuit, so your output will just be a divided down version of the input.

Comment: YES, its not a final design, later it will be supplied from a reference or something else (both current and voltage adjust circuits)

Comment: your resistors for the diff amp need to be EXACTLY matched, not just the same color bands. Try changing one of those 10k resistors in the sim to 10009 ohms and another to 9990 ohms and see the results. You can measure each resistor on a strip and try to find matches, or you can build up ~9.5k with a few cheapies in series then add a 1k trim pot so that you can dial in 10k exactly. It will help, especially when the diff amp's two inputs are very close in voltage.

Comment: you also need to pull 3.5 - 10ma at all times from the 317 to satify the datasheet's `Minimum load current
to maintain regulation` figure. You can pull that before the load with a resistor, but that changes with output voltage, so a constant current sink like an lm334 set to whatever you need would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your current limit loop may be unstable in practice. There is no (little) loop compensation in it, and you have very high gain (comparator). A simple simulation may not show this instability.

Also, the LM224 cannot pull down closer than ~ 0.7 V to its GND, so it likely can't fully turn off the NPN. Add a diode in series with its emitter to effectively increase its VBE; you may even eliminate that comparator and drive directly with the difference amplifier (perhaps increase its gain).

Comment: But the simulation shows -3v on the output of the comp. , its "Vcc -" i connected to -3v, so it will pull below 0,7? or im reading the datasheet wrong?

How would you compensate the "small" loop?

Comment: You have -3.3V for the neg. supply; it has a PNP output device, so can't actively pulldown well within 0.7 V of this (e.g. below -2.6 V). I don't know what simulator you are using, but it may not be accurate in this condition. Try adding a diode in series; or a pull-down resistor (maybe 1k from the LM224's output to -3.3V).